# Codename one static initialisation block ignored

Tags: codenameone

Seems like static initialisation blocks are not working in CN1, for example, registering of custom externalisable class:

```
public class User {

    static {
        Util.register("User", User.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

However, in one of CN1 blogs I found that this is recommended way to register externalisable classes. Can't find answer in the documentation. Have I missed something or CN1 does not actually support static initialisation blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initialization works just fine.

What you did won't work though... E.g.:

```
Object o = storage.readObject(...);
```

Assuming o is a `User` the class wasn't initialized yet hence no static initializer, no register call and the serialization code will fail.

That is why we always register in the `init(Object)` method of the main class and never in a static initializer.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed problem with storage by moving Util.register() to init() method. I checked in my program and it seems that I use that class only after reading it from storage.